# Are there stats of how users open push notifications (tap/swipe or just unlock and lookup the app)

Tags: android, ios, user-interface, push-notification, push

There is a difference between a user that swipes a push notification (on the lock screen) or simply tap it (on the today screen) when it arrives - and between a user that looks up the app icon and open it.

The former "injects" the payload into the app and the latter doesn't.

For example, upon a whatsapp's incoming push alert the user can do the following:
1. Tap/swipe the push message --> results in whatsapp app immediately open and show the incoming message
2. unlock the phone, look up the whatsapp icon and use it to launch --> results in seeing the list of conversations, then the user need to select the latest incoming message and only then see the text.

QUESTION IS - are there any stats of how users behave?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about how remote notification is handled in client side. If you check iOS UIApplicationDelegate, it's pretty clear.

1. Tap/swipe the push message

This triggers notification handler with payload, technically callback

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
```

And client side can handle payload in "userInfo", a dictionary containing information from server, such as message content, and client side is free to show the message.

2. look up the whatsapp icon and use it to launch

This has nothing to do with remote notification, it just launch App. If it's not opened before, it calls

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

If it's opened before and stay in background, it calls

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
```

and

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

It not read any remote notification information, of course cannot open server pushed message.

3. Since iOS 8 a new way is introduced for remote notification named "interactive notification", thus you don't need to open App, but can directly respond in notification banner or locked screen. Remind to use this callback

   - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler

If you feel confused about remote notification, and even bother by hosting your own remote notification server, there are some good SDK to help. Check http://api.streethawk.com/v1/docs/ios-introduction.html.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborated answer. However, my questions was about statistics from which I can understand how many users in real life actually swipe the push notification. We've implemented a special functionality that kicks off when swiping the push notifications to launch the app but not sure how many are actually using it.

Comment: StreetHawk has statistics of user action, you can try it.